# Use PCRE2 Regex to group phrase before colon AND group comma separated values

Tags: regex, csv, text-processing

I have what seems to be a simple task but isn't working for me. Using only PCRE2 Regex (nothing else), I am trying to collect a phrase before the first colon at the beginning of a line, then *separate* and place *within the same group* all the comma separated values.

Here are some sample texts:

```
Shapes: circle, rectangle, triangle  
Junk line: this part, here, should work, but: make sure, that last colon, isn't caught
```

Should be captured as such:

**Group 1:**

```
Shapes:
```

**Group 2:**

```
circle  
rectangle  
triangle
```

---

**Group 1:**

```
Junk line:
```

**Group 2:**

```
this part  
here  
should work  
but: make sure  
that last colon  
isn't caught
```

I know comma separated values can be captured many ways, like this:

```
([^,]+)
```

But if I try to add anything to the beginning, the match stops after the first comma, so this:

```
(.*):([^,]+)
```

Will not work (plus it captures the second colon in a line anyway).  Any help is appreciated!

**EDITED TO ADD:** The matching should stop at the end of the line, so something like this:

```
One: two, three  
Yellow: Blue, Green
```

Should not catch `Yellow` as part of `two, three`.  `Yellow` should be caught as a new instance of group one

Comment: Out of curiosity. Why do you need a regex? Why not simple text processing and splitting on colon and commas? It is doable if I understand your request correctly (although the colon part is weirdly phrased), but I don't follow why so many people try to overuse regex on literally anything.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, see next comment about them as I am afraid I'll run out of room in this comment. For the wording about the colon, my apologies, I am ESL.  The regex is needed as it's used by Exiftool to parse image metadata, certainly not my first choice!

See

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PCRE2, language independant, I'd use:

```
(^[^:]+:|\G(?!^))\h*([^,\r\n]+),?
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/hUMAtF/1)

Comment: Thanks, that one seems to work a bit better than the other suggestion

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work for your case if I understood correctly:

```
(?:^|\n)([^:]+):|(?:\s?)([^,\n]+)(?:,|$)
```

Basically, first you match anything from the start of line or newline until a colon `(?:^|\n)([^:]+):`. If you want to include the colon (as examples show but the 1st sentence says otherwise), just move the capture group to include the colon.

Then you have an alternative of matching phrases consisting of:

- `(?:\s?)` - non-captured optional whitespace
- `([^,\n]+)` - anything that's not a comma or newline
- `(?:,|$)` - either a non-captured comma or end of line

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/qOS9Hc/1

But as I mentioned in a comment below the question, I'm not sure why you're using a regex for that. It's much simplier with basic text processing - splitting by colon, then splitting by `,`

Also note that this can capture some other kind of inputs, unless you add `(?!^)(?<=\G)` at the beginning of the 2nd alternative:

```
(?:^|\n)([^:]+):|(?!^)(?<=\G)(?:\s?)([^,\n]+)(?:,|$)
```

Which makes sure that the 1st match of the phrase with a colon appears at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested solutions.  Unfortunately,[the first one](https://regex101.com/r/fNGXW0/1) has the last word of a line grouping with the phrase before the colon on the next line and misses parentheses if hey are right after a comma.

[The second one](https://regex101.com/r/eZy9XT/1) works slightly better but still misses some matches at the end of a line.

Thank you for trying though, this one is not as easy as it seems it should be.

Comment: Multiline requirement wasn't specified accurately in the initial question. The syntax with parantheses and without space wasn't at all. I would edit it since it's still not too hard to achieve but then I'm afraid you'd come up with more random edge cases. It really seems like a job for regular text parsing rather than a regex.

Comment: Or actually, I decided to update it as it was quite a nice challenge/practice @Tushar Bhutt But I won't update it any further if any other "weirdness" comes up. The regex is a bit of an abomination already as it is.

Comment: Thanks, and once again, I'm not using regex for fun, it's because I have to.  Your opinion on the abomination of the text format is noted, I wish I had control over that too but I don't.  But thanks for the regex code, it did work with a minor tweak for my own purposes.